# JavaScript(HTML5) Game Engine

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Maybe is tutorial's, article's, book's or something other to how design Game Engine(-Library, Framework) Architecture in JavaScript(HTML5 Canvas or DOM)?
I am searching in Google but don't find.
And have one more question: Why one framework's use Anonymous functions in this style(1) and other in this style(2)?
1:

```
var Engine = (function() {
    var version = '0.0.1';

    return {
        version : version
    }
})();
```

2:

```
(function(window) {
    window.Engine = {
        version : '0.0.1'
    };
})(window);
```

Or something like. Which is better?

Comment: Have you seen Construct 2?  http://www.scirra.com It's an HTML5 game engine that cuts out a lot of overhead for you

Comment: @AlexisWilke Please fix all issues with a post instead of only removing a "thank you" line.

Answer (score 5):

Neither of those are better, they are functionally pretty similar. The second one is guaranteed to attach Engine to window and the first one will only do so if it is executed in the top-level.

The second one is used by jQuery and is arguably more common.

If you are very new to Canvas, there is the book [Foundation HTML5 Canvas: For Games and Entertainment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232919). It is a pretty average book, and only really useful if you are very new to this stuff. It might help you get started though.

Designing a good game-engine is a pretty broad and platform-agnostic topic though. If I were you I would seek out articles on designing engines in particular, moreso based on the type of engine you want to make (FPS? Point and click game? Side scrolling game?)

How you design it will depend on the type of game a lot more than it will depend on than the language and platform involved.

So what I'd really suggest is that you read [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Crockford to get an idea of how JavaScript is different from other langauges. Then search the net for more general articles on game engine development, considering the type of game engine over the language.

Comment: Type: 2D/Isometric.
Simon, thanks for awesome reply!

Comment: Okay, then you'll actually want to see this tutorial: http://glacialflame.com/category/tutorial/ as well as take a look at what Neuroflux is doing lately: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/n7VAu/

Comment: Simon, Thanks too for other answer.
I'm before read glacialflame.com tutorial's and try experiment's with this, but my engine is now about 250~ code line.
<pre>Engine.render = 'canvas'; // Canvas, DOM, Engine.loadImg(), Engine.drawIsoMap(), Engine.tileWidth/Engine.tileHeight, Engine.map[], Engine.drawText(), </pre> and with this Engine can draw Isometric map.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to have a look on https://html5gameengine.com/ There you can find a list of HTML5 / JavaScript game engines that are supported with a large communities and refer to their official documentations.